# How to use the @app.callback function with two inputs as dropdowns?

Tags: python, callback

I have been trying to create an interactive dashboard in Python using the @app.callback function with two inputs. My dataset layout can be summarized into 4 main columns.

[image]

I'd like Geography and Time Period to manifest in the form of dropdowns (therefore use the Dcc. dropdown function. The first dropdown will filter the dataset according to the Geography and the second one will define the "Period time - MAT, L12w or L4w) within the country. Therefore somehow the second dropdown is to be integrated within the first dropdown.

I am familiarized with both the dropdown and @app.callback function. But I can't seem to find a script that fuses both. Important note: the output desired is a pie chart that distinguishes Manufacturers' (Column 2) value share (column 4) according to the selected Geography and time Period.  I am guessing the mystery resides in the app.layout structure. However, I tried everything and the code won't work.

Also, you will find the code I have done so far attached. The important bit is from "#DESIGN APP LAYOUT" onwards.

```
import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
pd.options.display.width=None


data =  pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Sara.Munoz\OneDrive - Unilever\Documents\Sarita.csv', 
                            encoding = "ISO-8859-1",
                            )
df=data
print(df.head())
cols=df.columns
print(cols)

###RE-ARRANGE DATASET###
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Geography Node Name', 'Geography Id', 'Geography Level',
       'Category Node Name', 'Category Id', 'Category Level',
       'Global Manufacturer Name', 'Global Manufacturer Id',
       'Brand Position Type', 'Brand Position Name', 'Brand Position Id',
       'Local Brand Name', 'Local Brand Id', 'Measure',
       'Currency or Unit of Measure','Latest Available Date'],value_vars=['MAT','L12W','L4W'], var_name='Period',value_name='Data')

for col in df.columns:
    print(col)


###CLEAN DATASET###

df.rename(columns = {'Geography Node Name':'Geography','Category Node Name':'Category',
                     'Global Manufacturer Name':'Manufacturer','Geography Level':'GLevel'},inplace = True)


df.drop(["Geography Id", "Category Id","Global Manufacturer Id","Brand Position Type",
                  "Brand Position Name","Brand Position Id","Local Brand Name","Local Brand Id","Latest Available Date",
         "Currency or Unit of Measure"], axis = 1, inplace=True)

print("SEE BELOW NEW DATASET")

print(df.head())

#####FOR VALUE SHARE

print("FOR VALUE SHARE")

df2 = df.loc[df['GLevel'] == 5]
df2 = df2.loc[df2['Measure'] == 'Value Share']
df2 = df2.loc[df2['Category'] == 'Toothpaste']
df2 = df2[df2.Manufacturer != 'ALL MANUFACTURERS']
df2 = df2[df2.Category != 'Oral Care']
df2.drop(["GLevel", "Category","Category Level"], axis = 1, inplace=True)
print(df2.head())

#####FOR VOLUME SHARE

print("FOR VOLUME SHARE")

df3 = df.loc[df['GLevel'] == 5]
df3 = df3.loc[df3['Measure'] == 'Volume Share']
df3 = df3.loc[df3['Category'] == 'Toothpaste']
df3 = df3[df3.Manufacturer != 'ALL MANUFACTURERS']
df3 = df3[df3.Category != 'Oral Care']
df3.drop(["GLevel", "Category","Category Level"], axis = 1, inplace=True)
df3=df3.sort_values(['Geography', 'Period'],ascending = [True, True])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df3=df3[['Geography','Period','Manufacturer','Measure','Data']]
print(df3)

###############################################################################

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-1",
            options=[
                             {'label': 'Indonesia', 'value': 'Indonesia'},
                            {'label': 'France', 'value': 'France'},
                             {'label': 'Vietnam', 'value': 'Vietnam'},
                             {'label': 'Chile', 'value': 'Chile'},
                            {'label': 'United Arab Emirates', 'value': 'United Arab Emirates'},
                             {'label': 'Morocco', 'value': 'Morocco'},
                             {'label': 'Russian Federation', 'value': 'Russian Federation'},
                            {'label': 'China', 'value': 'China'},
                             {'label': 'Greece', 'value': 'Greece'},
                             {'label': 'Netherlands', 'value': 'Netherlands'},
                            {'label': 'Austria', 'value': 'Austria'},
                             {'label': 'Germany', 'value': 'Germany'},
                             {'label': 'Switzerland', 'value': 'Switzerland'},
                            {'label': 'Italy', 'value': 'Italy'},
                             {'label': 'Denmark', 'value': 'Denmark'},
                             {'label': 'Norway', 'value': 'Norway'},
                             {'label': 'Sweden', 'value': 'Sweden'}
        ],
            multi=True,
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-2",
           options=[
                             {'label': 'MAT', 'value': 'MAT'},
                            {'label': 'L12W', 'value': 'L12W'},
                             {'label': 'L4W', 'value': 'L4W'}
        ],
            multi=True,
        ),
        html.Div([], id="plot1", children=[])
    ], style={'display': 'flex'})


@app.callback(
    Output("plot1", "children"),
    [Input("dropdown-1", "value"), Input("dropdown-2", "value")],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)

def get_graph(entered_Geo, entered_Period):
    
    fd = df2[(df3['Geography']==entered_Geo) &
             (df3['Period']==entered_Period)]

    g1= fd.groupby(['Manufacturer'],as_index=False). \
            mean()
    g1 = g1
    plot1= px.pie(g1, values='Data', names='Manufacturer', title="Value MS")


    return[dcc.Graph(figure=plot1)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

#DESIGN APP LAYOUT##############################################################################

````
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Label("Geography:",style={'fontSize':30, 'textAlign':'center'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown1',
        options=[{'label': s, 'value': s} for s in sorted(df3.Geography.unique())],
        value=None,
        clearable=False
    ),
    html.Label("Period:", style={'fontSize':30, 'textAlign':'center'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown2',
                 options=[],
                 value=[],
                 multi=False),
    html.Div([
                
                        html.Div([ ], id='plot1'),
                        html.Div([ ], id='plot2')

                        
                    ], style={'display': 'flex'}),


    ])

##############
# Populate the Period dropdown with options and values
@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown2', 'options'),
    Output('dropdown2', 'value'),
    Input('dropdown1', 'value'),
)
def set_period_options(chosen_Geo):
    dff = df3[df3.Geography==chosen_Geo]
    Periods = [{'label': s, 'value': s} for s in df3.Period.unique()]
    values_selected = [x['value'] for x in Periods]
    return Periods, values_selected

# Create graph component and populate with pie chart
@app.callback([Output(component_id='plot1', component_property='children'),
               Output(component_id='plot2', component_property='children')],
              Input('dropdown2', 'value'),
              Input('dropdown1', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_graph(selected_Period, selected_Geo):
    if len(selected_Period) == 0:
        return no_update

    else:
        #Volume Share
        dff3 = df3[(df3.Geography==selected_Geo) & (df3.Period==selected_Period)]
        #Value Share
        dff2 = df2[(df2.Geography==selected_Geo) & (df2.Period==selected_Period)]
        #####

        fig1 = px.pie(dff2, values='Data', names='Manufacturer', title=" Value MS")
        fig2 = px.pie(dff3, values='Data', names='Manufacturer', title=" Volume MS")
        table = 
        
        return [dcc.Graph(figure=fig1),
            dcc.Graph(figure=fig2) ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).